# Running old project on Spring Tool Suite

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, spring-tool-suite

I have a spring boot project based on JDK 1.8 and Gradle 2.14.1 . I am struggling get it running on my Apple Silicone M1 Mac. When I try to import the project using Spring Tool suite it fails with following error.

```
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not fetch model of type 'GradleBuild' using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-bin.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:69)
    at org.gradle.inte
```

Any inputs on how to resolve the issue is much appreciated as I am struggling on this for sometime now. Works without an issue on Intel Macs.

Comment: It seems like a connection issue , are you sure the site is accessible over your network ? and are you using any vpn or proxy ? i had the same issue and a proxy set up for STS fixed the issue for me .

Comment: I am not sure whether this old Gradle version that is used in the project is still supported by the Gradle Integration for Eclipse (the Buildship project). I would recommend to run the Groovy build locally from the command line to produce Eclipse project metadata and then import the project into your IDE as an existing project (not as a Gradle project).

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse above 4 replaces Gradle with a non-string value in the system properties. You can update Gradle above version 3 from [here](http://dist.springsource.com/snapshot/TOOLS/gradle/nightly)